# Can I store an xml string in a resources file (.resx), without it getting encoded with &lt; and &gt;?

Tags: asp.net, xml, encoding, resx

In Visual Studio, I can put an xml string into the "Value" field. However, when I open up the actual .resx file, I see that it has been encoded to have `&lt;` and `&gt;`. I want the .resx file to be able to be edited manually without using the Visual Studio UI, and obviously this is messy with the `&gt;` and `&lt;`s. Could I somehow do this without the encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for the time being: use JSON for the value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I usually wrap values in my resx files in `CDATA` if I don't want to deal with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Of course this is a mess too if you have `CDATA` in your xml string. Also as soon as you edit with the Visual Studio UI again, it will revert back to `&lt;` `&gt;`